# element.index() jQuery not returning the correct index

Tags: html, jquery

I was trying to make a FAQ system with jQuery with some animations.
What I do is: I get the box (with the question) index, and use this index for selecting the box (with the answer, which is below the question box). But somehow, the index returns the double of the value that it should return. This is my actual code:

```js
function showFaqAnswers() {
  var questionBox = $('.question-box')
  var answerBox = $('.answer-box')
  questionBox.click(function() {
    var thisIndex = $(this).index()
    if ($(this).hasClass('goShow')) {
      $(this).removeClass('goShow')
      answerBox.eq(thisIndex).slideToggle(250)
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('goShow')
      answerBox.eq(thisIndex).slideToggle(250)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions-wraper">
  <div class="question-box">
    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>

    <div class="question-text">
      <p>Which payment methods are accepted?</p>
    </div>
    <!-- question-text -->

    <div class="bottom-arrow">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- bottom-arrow -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!-- clear -->
  </div>
  <!-- question-box -->
  <div class="answer-box">
    <p>The currently accepted methods are MercadoPago and PayPal.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- answer-box -->

  <div class="question-box">
    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>

    <div class="question-text">
      <p>How many ghost clients are detected?</p>
    </div>
    <!-- question-text -->

    <div class="bottom-arrow">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- bottom-arrow -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!-- clear -->
  </div>
  <!-- question-box -->
  <div class="answer-box">
    <p>It's hard to say because we are constantly updating our strings and detection methods, but it's more than 1000.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- answer-box -->

  <div class="question-box">
    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>

    <div class="question-text">
      <p>Is the tool really safe?</p>
    </div>
    <!-- question-text -->

    <div class="bottom-arrow">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- bottom-arrow -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!-- clear -->
  </div>
  <!-- question-box -->
  <div class="answer-box">
    <p>Of course. All your data is safe at your database, which has an end-to-end encryption. You don't need to worry about this.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- answer-box -->

  <div class="question-box">
    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>

    <div class="question-text">
      <p>Is there a partnership plan?</p>
    </div>
    <!-- question-text -->

    <div class="bottom-arrow">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- bottom-arrow -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!-- clear -->
  </div>
  <!-- question-box -->
  <div class="answer-box">
    <p>Yes. If you would like to be a partner, simply go to our Discord server (the button below) and open a ticket, the support team will quickly answer you.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- answer-box -->
</div>
<!-- questions-wraper -->
```

So what basically happens is: Instead of showing the next box with the answer for the question, it shows the the box that comes after the next one. And I've already console logged the index of the element (thisIndex), and it returns the double value of what it should return. I don't know why, can someone help me?

Comment: Where do you call your function?

Comment: I suggest not using `index()` but rather wrap the question and its corresponding answer in an element. Then you can use `.closest('.wrapper').find('.answer-box')` to get the answer associated with the question.

Comment: Try `$(this).index('.question-box')` instead, if you don't specify the class then all sibling elements inside the parent will be counted.